# $rootScope.$watch not working with object in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have got two controllers. I define a $rootScope variable in parent controller and change it according to clicked dropdown.

I want the change to be reflected in the child controller.

**Parent Controller**

```
$rootScope.variable = {'attr1':true, 'attr2':false, 'attr3':false}//initializing
vm.clickedDropDown = function(index) {
    $rootScope.variable = {'attr1':false, 'attr2':false, 'attr3':false }
    switch (index) {
        case 1: 
            $rootScope.variable={'attr1':true, 'attr2':false, 'attr3':false}
            break;
        case 2: 
            $rootScope.variable={'attr1':false, 'attr2':true, 'attr3':false}
            break;
        case 3: 
            $rootScope.variable={'attr1':false, 'attr2':false, 'attr3':true}
            break;
    }
}
```

**Child Controller**

```
$rootScope.$watch($rootScope.variable,function(){
  console.log($rootScope.variable);
  console.log("changed");
},true)
```

The variable is changing and i am able to see the change in variable as output.

Comment: I would use `$broadcast` from parent to child controller. This approach is not expensive because broadcasting happens once. Anyways its not good practice regards your example.

Comment: How about `$rootScope.watch('variable', ...)`?

Comment: throws error as variable is undefined

Comment: Can i have the code with $broadcast.

Comment: well when you watch the $rootScope you dont need to specify it in the watch attribute so $rootScope.$watch('variable', function(newVal, oldVal,scope){//logix},true}); if this is a function then you need to return the function in the watcher.... 

as a rule of thumb if you dont have to watch though you should use $broadcast

Comment: Broadcast from parent to child: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/713/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your watch is wrong.

Either:

```
$rootScope.$watch('variable' ,function(){
  console.log($rootScope.variable);
  console.log("changed");
},true);
```

or

```
$rootScope.$watch(
    function() { 
        return $rootScope.variable; 
    },
    function(){
        console.log($rootScope.variable);
        console.log("changed");
    },true);
```

Comment: Option 2 worked out. Thanks. will mark it correct answer in  few minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use scope because the child controller will inherit the parent controller and have access to any scope variables defined in scope and rootScope

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    <pre>{{ debug }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.name = 'Superhero';
}

function ChildCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.debug = '';

    $scope.$watch('name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.debug += " value changed...";
    });
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heavyhorse/aqbhco7m/

Comment: Take care of primitive type and inherence of scopes